# Item counting on search page of magento

Tags: magento

When we search a product in magento it shows result on search page with pager, BUT i want to show items counting without using pager of magento.

I want a custom code to show total number of items on search result.

If anyone get answer please update me.

Thanks

Comment: It depends where you need show this information. If you are in some search block, maybe `$this->getCollection()->count()` is available.

Comment: Ya this code is used to count products in pager, how i use this on search page without calling pager.

Comment: Thanks Rafael Kassner It's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $this->getCollection()->count() in your list.phtml file and it counts total products found in search result.

Comment: This only show the no.of results on current page.Not the whole page result

Comment: don't set pager counter in your collection, call collection model without setting pager settings

Comment: $total_records = $this->getTotalNum() ; 
This can easily solve the case

Comment: 1.its give current page count:$this->getCollection()->count();  2.$this->getResultCount(): gives search result count. 3.$this->getCollection()->getSize(): total count